# Is there a way to trigger jquery click function from another page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Is there a way to trigger click function in a different page?

First Page:

```
<a>Create</a>

<script>
$('#createSp').click(function () {
window.location.href = "../Admin/UserAdministration.aspx";
$('#btn_create_user').trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

Second Page:

```
<asp:HyperLink ClientIDMode="Static" ID="btn_create_user" CssClass="btn ci_btn btn-default" runat="server">Create User</asp:HyperLink>

<script>
$('#btn_create_user').click(function () {});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't directly trigger a click on a different page. The current DOM and everything else will get reset & unloaded before the new page is loaded. But you can leave a cookie or pass your click action as an anchor hash via the url.

```
<button id='createSp'>Create</button>

<script>
$('#createSp').click(function () {
      window.location.href = "../Admin/UserAdministration.aspx#create";
});
</script>
```

and in your 2nd page

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); //get the string after the hash
  if(hash =='create'){
      $('#btn_create_user').trigger('click');
  }
});
```